# Python NumPy shape

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone please explain this code to me

```
case = np.array([[1,2], [2,4], [3,5]])
```

I understand the above gives *2 columns and 3 rows*.

But the code below I don't understand. Please help me to understand it.

```
np.arange(0, case.shape[0]+4)
```

Comment: `case.shape` is `(2,3)`, `case.shape[0]` is `2`, so the code is just `np.arange(6)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang. Aside from the shape being (3, 2), you are absolutely correct

Answer (score 1):

`np.arange()` returns evenly spaced values within a given interval.

In this case, since `case.shape[0]` is the first axis of the array, which has `3` arrays in it, the range goes from `0` to `3+4=7` (end not included).

Answer (score 0):

```
case = np.array([[1,2], [2,4], [3,5]])
case
array([[1, 2],
   [2, 4],
   [3, 5]])
```

Numpy.arange will provide a series of numbers starts from 0 to case.shape[0] +4 . Here case.shape is (3,2) (Three Rows and Two Columns) . So Case[0] will be 3 and case[1] will be  2 . So np.arrange will  be a series of numbers from 0 to 3+4 = 7 where 0 is included and 7 is excluded and output will be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6